# QuickBooks Online PHP SDK regenerate token

Tags: php, sdk, quickbooks-online

I have small question about QuickBooks Online SDK. Actually SDK working fine but once token expired new token will not auto regenerate. Actually auto reconnect is not in sample code and documentation. I need know how it will work?

Answer (score 0):

Oauth Access tokens expire 180 days from the date they were created. Oauth token Reconnect API can be called between 151 days and 179 days (after 5 months and before expiry).

- Requesting a token to be renewed before 151 days  results in this error `Token Refresh Window Out of Bounds`.
- Requesting a token to be renewed after 179 days results in this error `OAuth Token Rejected`.

To prevent your user from needing to sign-on to reauthorize access to your app every six months, follow these guidelines:

1. Initiate the OAuth workflow to generate the initial access token for
   the user.
2. Store the access token creation date within your app.
3. Call the Reconnect API between 151 days and 179 days of that creation
   date to renew the Oauth access token.
4. Repeat steps 2 and 3 after getting new token.